# tcp_outgoing_address: cannot connect to website

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a LinuxMint running in a virtual box. I have installed a squid3 proxy server and it is working.

However, if I want to add a tcp_outgoing_address it is not working.

I am using the default configuration and just added the following line at the end:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 51.51.51.51
```

But after restarting the server I always get an error:
The requested URL cannot be retrieved

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Serverfault is for network and system administration in a business environment.  Try posting to http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thx! Posted it there, too. If anybody is interested: http://superuser.com/questions/962146/tcp-outgoing-address-cannot-connect-to-website